# From where I can get the country combo box in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use country combo box in my desktop application in C#. from where I can get this? Because instead of writing all I want a combo box containing list of all country.

kindly help!

Comment: Desktop application then why did u add asp.net tag

Comment: So desktop application (winforms, wpf) or web application (asp.net)?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the globalization namespace to generate a list of countries.

```
public static List<string> GetCountryList()
{
    List<string> cultureList = new List<string>();

    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
    {
        RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);

        if (!(cultureList.Contains(region.EnglishName)))
        {
            cultureList.Add(region.EnglishName);
        }
    }
    return cultureList;
}
```

Remember to add `using System.Globalization`
If you need the native names, you can replace the `region.EnglishName` with `region.NativeName`.

Answer (score 3):

You can download CSV or XML of all countries and insert into your Database and fetch from Database to fill ComboBox OR you can fill Combobox from XML also

http://www.andrewpatton.com/countrylist.html

Comment: I don't want to insert it in db, to add in combo box. I am creating desktop application. using c sharp

Comment: +1 static list populate from XML on startup